# Setting up Public/Private Key Pair for Linux Login (not SSH)

Tags: linux, desktop, key-authentication

I've searched Google and this site for the answer to this question, and haven't been able to find the answer. My goal is to use a public/private key pair to login to my desktop computer from a USB stick instead of entering a username and password. I know that this is possible on Windows with some specialized software, but I haven't found anything about this for Linux. Is it possible, and if it is, where do I need to start?

Thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_usb / https://wiki.debian.org/pamusb or https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/

Comment: Thanks! The pam_usb project looks exactly like what I am looking for. @Patrick Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I don't know enough about it to provide an answer. If you want to write up a short answer to your own question (stackexchange lets  you do this) about how it works, and how it solved your problem, you're more than welcome to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444871/setting-up-public-private-key-pair-for-linux-login-not-ssh?noredirect=1#comment806798_444871), [Pam_usb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_usb) is exactly what I have been looking for. I have not made use of it yet, though.